# Sort by parameter to backend database

Tags: sql, rest

How is a sorting logic specified in the REST API normally handled by the backend database?

supposing the REST API request is

```
https://<<some api>>/?sortBy=-id,name
```

is there a easier way of converting the above rest api sortBy parameter without having to do some regex to seperate the string by commas, and then check if the first character contains a dash to form the below sql request?

```
SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id ASC, name DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma delimited strings don't have to be split by regex.. the following c# would do it, for example:

```
string sort = Request["sortBy"];
if(sort != null){
  foreach(string s in sort.Split(',')){
    string direction = "DESC";
    if(s[0] == '-')
      direction = "ASC";
    if(permittedColumnsList.Contains(s.Replace("-", ""))
      sql = sql + s.Replace("-", "") + " " + direction + ",";
}
sql = sql.Remove(sql.Length - 1); // drop last comma
```

This is still parsing and looking for the first dash though, something you seem not to want.

If you were prepared to store all the permissible sort ops in a dictionary it gets simpler looking:

```
//column dictionary mapping acceptable parameters to the sql that
//implements them
colDict["-id"]="id ASC,";
colDict["id"]="id DESC,";
colDict["-name"]="name ASC,";
colDict["name"]="name DESC,";

string sort = Request["sortBy"];
if(sort != null){
  foreach(string s in sort.Split(',')){
    if(colDict.ContainsKey(s))
      sql = sql + colDict[s];
}
sql = sql.Remove(sql.Length - 1); // drop last comma
```

I think there's only so far you should go in looking to simplify things. It wouldn't be wise to blindly take what the user typed into the URL, and shove it in the sql suffixed with ASC if they put a - (I keep expecting - to be DESC) because that's a security risk. By building a dictionary of permitted values you isolate yourself from that risk. The dictionary can be built programmatically so it doesn't need altering manually every time the query schema changes